# Jax RS Response producing application/json: how to wrap a simple string?

Tags: json, jax-rs

Consider my Rest Service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticateUser(CredentialsDTO credentialsDTO) {

    try {
        authService.login(credentialsDTO.getUsername(), credentialsDTO.getPassword());

    } catch (WrongCredentialsException e) {
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("WrongCredentialsException").build();
    } catch (AccountLockedException e) {
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("AccountLockedException").build();
    }

    String token = issueToken(credentialsDTO.getUsername());
    return Response.ok().header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token).build();
}
```

Is it OK to return a String (such as "AccountLockedException") in the entity, **although I declared application/json as content type ?**

Do I have to **wrap the error message in a Json object** before sending it back ?

I am facing the problem on the client side when I am trying to parse the response as a Json, but only text comes back when an error occurs.

Comment: Use `.entity("\"" + "WrongCredentialsException" + "\"")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should wrap your string in JSON.
This is how your code may look in this case:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticateUser(CredentialsDTO credentialsDTO) {

    try {
        authService.login(credentialsDTO.getUsername(), credentialsDTO.getPassword());
    } catch (WrongCredentialsException e) {
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .entity(new JSONObject().put("message", "WrongCredentialsException").toString())
            .build();
    } catch (AccountLockedException e) {
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .entity(new JSONObject().put("message", "AccountLockedException").toString())
            .build();
    }

    String token = issueToken(credentialsDTO.getUsername());
    return Response.ok().header(AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token).build();
}
```

Or you may even create a separate class for these exceptions and serialise them with your default JSON serialiser library.